# Oracle XML validation against XSD has unexpected results

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

I am generating an XML which must conform to a standard XSD.

So far I registered the XSD, I created a table with an XMLType column, tied to the xsd definition as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE DEVEL.SEPE_E8_XMLDOCS
(
  MIOM     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  SEPE     VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  KTHR     VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  XML_DOC  SYS.XMLTYPE
)
XMLTYPE COLUMN XML_DOC store  AS clob XMLSCHEMA "SEPE/E8_v1.xsd"  ELEMENT "OvertimesE8" ;
```

expecting that, if a generated XML document does not get validated accross the XSD, INSERT will fail and raise an exception.

*Which is not the case - always.*

**Case 1** - this field (Sex- 0:Male, 1:Female)

```
        <xs:element name="f_sex" nillable="false">
            <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>ΦΥΛΟ - (0) ΑΝΤΡΑΣ - (1) ΓΥΝΑΙΚΑ</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

Validation *works as expected*. If I try to put '9' or 'X' on that field, INSERT is rejected.

**Case 2 - This field:**

```
        <xs:element name="f_afm" nillable="false">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>ΑΡΙΘΜΟΣ ΦΟΡΟΛΟΓΙΚΟΥ ΜΗΤΡΩΟΥ (Α.Φ.Μ.)</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([0-9]){9}" />
                    <xs:length value="9" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

This field is the employees Tax ID, it is expected to be numeric and exactly 9 numbers long.

Well, **this field, validates always, even when it is not valid**. No matter if I shorten it, no matter if I put deliberately an alphabetic character, INSERT succeeds.

---

So far, I tried :

1.

```
ALTER TABLE Devel.Sepe_e8_xmldocs ADD
CONSTRAINT Sepe_e8_xmldocs_c01
 CHECK (Xmlisvalid(Xml_doc) = 1) 
    ENABLE
 VALIDATE;
```

With this constraint, INSERT fails ALWAYS, even with valid XML.

2.

```
DECLARE
   Xmldoc   Xmltype;
   ISVALID NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT   X.Xml_doc
     INTO   Xmldoc
     FROM   Sepe_e8_xmldocs X
    WHERE   ROWNUM <= 1;

   ISVALID := Xmldoc.Isschemavalid ('SEPE/E8_v1.xsd');

   IF ISVALID = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('valid');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('NOT VALID');
   END IF;
END;
```

ISVALID will always hold 0, even with valid documents.

```
DECLARE
   Xmldoc   Xmltype;
   ISVALID NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT   X.Xml_doc
     INTO   Xmldoc
     FROM   Sepe_e8_xmldocs X
    WHERE   ROWNUM <= 1;


   IF Xmlisvalid(Xml_doc) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('valid');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_line ('NOT VALID');
   END IF;
END;
```

Result:

> Error at line 1
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 7:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'XMLISVALID' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 4:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

...and...

```
DECLARE
   Xmldoc   Xmltype;
BEGIN
   SELECT   X.Xml_doc
     INTO   Xmldoc
     FROM   Sepe_e8_xmldocs X
    WHERE   ROWNUM <= 1;

   --  xmldoc := xmltype(xml).createSchemaBasedXML('SEPE/E8_v1.xsd');
   Xmldoc.Schemavalidate;
END;
```

...resulting...

> LSX-00333: literal "11" is not valid with respect to the pattern

After a little research, I found out that this 11 is the month, whose definition is:

```
    <xs:element name="f_month" nillable="false">
        <xs:annotation><xs:documentation>ΜΗΝΑΣ - (1-12) Ιανουάριος - Δεκέμβριος</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[1-9]|[1][0-2]"></xs:pattern>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
```

**Let me make clear that this rejected XML validates on online validators.**

So, I can not find a way, neither in SQL nor in PL/SQL to validate the xml document against the XSD.

*PS. Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.0*

Can you help me please?
Thank you.